# iOS Access Core Data Auto Generated Classes inside Today Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, today-extension

I generated a Core Data model with a table called ReadHistory. I selected to have this table codeine using Category/Extension as I needed to extend a transient property. I want to use this class inside of a today extension but when I try to build I get the error that this file could not be found.

```
#import "ReadHistory+CoreDataProperties.h"
```

I do not see that file to be added via compile sources.

How can I get the autogenerated classes to show in the today extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the file named `ReadHistory+CoreDataProperties.m` as a target to the extension also

[image]

Comment: The file doesn't exist in the project or show up on the side.

Comment: I managed to find the solution from this. In your image the jdsjsjdjsds.xcdatamodeid file had to be checked to go to the extension. This then made the error go away. Mind changing your answer to mention that and I'll mark as accepted.